# Full face helmet on E-bike

Tags: electric-bike, helmets

I am thinking to try a full face helmet on my E-bike for cold weather commuting. The main reasons would be the ones people consider for using the skiing helmet (a summer optimized helmet is too cold with too many holes, all my clothes match the season so why the helmet should be the same). Unlike skiing helmet that has been design for the different use case, some full face downhill helmet should, I assume, automatically feature the same and actually better protection that for a very frequent rider will do no harm.

Is there some analysis or argumentation ever published on using MTB downhill helmets on E-bikes for commuting, that would be worth to consider?

P.S. [Here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/54532/why-do-only-downhill-mountain-bikers-wear-full-face-helmets) is some discussion why full face helmets are not in common use between the cyclists. I am more asking if there is some advocacy for trying.

P.S. This question is about the "slow variety" of European E-bike that provides assist up till 25 km/h. Such speed is not unusual for an ordinary bicycle going downhill.

Comment: Are you referring to a helmet with a shield over the face, or a chin bar and an open face still?

Comment: Some brands are now marketing "e-bikes specific" helmets and some have features that are "cold weather friendly": removable ear pads, raincovers to limit water/air circulation, visors, adjustable ventilation,.... (Giro Bexley, Abus Pedelec Ace - not cheap but downhill helmets are not cheap either). What would be the reason to dismiss those? Also, I would in fact expect downhill helmet to have better ventilation than expected, as they are used in warmer temperature and need to compensate somehow for the closed environment.

Comment: You may even be able to find multi-certified skiing helmets.  The requirements are very similar.  I know you can get skate/bike helmets.

Comment: It is often not so easy to understand if the skiing helmet is also certified for biking, like this, for instance: https://www.galaxus.ch/en/s3/product/sweet-protection-trooper-2vi-sl-mips-helmet-bike-helmets-39360831 . It is even expensive, and listed between bicycle helmets, but still ....

Comment: "a summer optimized helmet is too cold with too many holes" I find that simply putting a rainproof cover over the helmet mostly fixes that.  When it's really cold, I put a cycling-optimized balaclava on underneath it, which keeps my face and ears warm.

Comment: @nightrider OK, looking a bit further, you're not likely to get dual certification.  Bike and skate helmets are tested to EN1078, while snow sports helmets  are tested to EN1077.  EN1077 has slightly higher impacts than the cycling standard, and is tested in colder conditions.  Unless there's a hard requirement (legal, insurance won't pay out, race rules) that you wear a bike helmet *certified to EN 1078* a ski helmet is likely to be a good choice.  It may even use materials that are better for a crash in below-freezing conditions.

Comment: @DavidW I had one of those rain covers.  I cut it up to use the fabric because it was almost invariably too warm - to the extent that I'd rather be wet with rain than sweat and I never carried it.  If I do need insulation with a helmet something thin and made of fabric underneath. Anyway it's my ears that need it first, below about +2°C depending on wind, wet, and how long the ride is,  while the rest of my head doesn't need anything until about -3°C.  So if the OP feels the cold it's  a good solution.

Comment: My $0.02, under "_Down to -10°C~15°F_"  at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/91158/48599

Comment: @ChrisH About rain covers and heat: It's easier on an e-bike to modulate the amount of heat the body produces (and the question is about e-bikes).

Comment: @Renaud good point, though whenever I've ridden e-bikes I've put proper effort in and got almost as hot as on normal bikes (inefficient geometry didn't help)

Comment: @ChrisH staying just under the cut-out requires a bit of training ;) - or to know where to exceed the 25km/h limit. Because indeed, the additional friction, bad aerodynamics and additional weight can cause more effort than on a normal bike.

Comment: E-bike helmets have their own ratings for higher speed impacts (presumably similar to the difference with EN-1078 vs 1077?). There is _definitely_ plenty of published advocacy for scaling the helmet ratings to the speeds expected, if that's what's being asked...? Anecdotally, a downhill helmet's chin bar helps "save face", my ears stay warm, & the lack of enclosing visor means less fog trouble in winter. And as the saying goes, "a half-shell helmet is half a helmet".

Comment: It is about 25 km/h E-bike, not 45 km/h one that is already more kind of motorbike.

Comment: @ProphetZarquon For 45km/h ebikes, another commonly quoted norm is NTA 8776 (no sure it's mandated though).

Comment: I use my bike helmets for skiing too (open for randonée, full-face enduro for alpine). Don't see the point of warm skiing helmets - it's much more flexible to add insulation to an airy bike helmet, than having a helmet that gets too warm in the sun or when having to climb some distance.

Answer (score 3):

I am a Canadian commuter.

I don't recall ever seeing any of my peers wearing downhill helmets in the winter.  Maybe once in a while you see someone with a full face snowboard helmet on, but I would assume those are people who already owned that $300-$500 accessory for snow boarding.

What is most common is a helmet in the style of the Nutcase brand with a Merino or similar cap underneath.

What you really need past -15C or so, depending on personal tolerance a bit, is goggles.  Proper goggles that seal against your face.  Your eyes just can't handle getting blasted with air that cold.  Any kind of full face shield is going to hopelessly fog up when you roll up to a stop light at -30 and breathe on it.  (I personally don't ride below -15 because my ride is in traffic for a while and I don't like riding in traffic with restricted peripheral vision.)

Comment: In my experience, downhill helmets do not have a full face shield. They're often coupled with goggles as you describe.

Comment: @Michael With the start of ski season approaching, I'm getting peppered with ads for ski helmets that have integrated face shields.  And i just looked on a certain online retailer, and there are a ton of them.

Comment: @PeterM I meant downhill _mountain bike_ helmets.